# Java how to fill array

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point, numbers, fill

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

float numberF[]=new float[7];
displayF(numberF);

}

public static void displayF(float x[]) {

    int one = 1;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
        sum = Math.pow(one, 2);
        x[row] = (int) sum;

        System.out.printf("%.0f.%.0f ",x[row], x[row] );
        one++;
    }

}
```

This method gives me this output:

```
1.1 4.4 9.9 16.16 25.25 36.36 49.49
```

But I need the array to store the numbers above with a for loop. Now it only stores `1.0 4.0 9.0 etc...`

Any suggestions of how to do it?

Comment: What does this have to do with stacks?

Comment: @Andy My misstake, changed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other more efficient ways to do it, but the easiest is just to parse what you are printing back into a float:

```
x[row] = Float.parseFloat(String.format("%.0f.%.0f", sum, sum));
```

---

As noted by SMA in the comments, this won't give an exact answer due to rounding errors. You can store the exact value if you change the array type to `BigDecimal`:

```
x[row] = new BigDecimal(String.format("%.0f.%.0f", sum, sum));
```

Comment: @SMA: sure, but that's the best you can do if the array you are filling is of type float[].